# QuickFIX suddenly stopped sending Logon requests

Tags: quickfix

Scenario:

1. FIX Initiator showed the below error in Event log file at below mentioned time in UTC

20230821-23:03:28: Disconnecting: Socket exception (/127.0.0.1:9823): java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

2. FIX Initiator tries 3 logon attempts after that no logon request was sent to FIX Acceptor

20230821-23:03:28: Initiated logon request

20230821-23:03:58: Initiated logon request

20230821-23:04:28: Initiated logon request

3. Last HeartBeat FIX Initiator received on 23:03:34.142 UTC
4. Session on FIX Acceptor side was heartbeating until 23:04:34 UTC. FIX Initiator didn't receive this HeartBeat.
   Assuming over the network, it has missed any packets on this connection.
5. FIX Acceptor did receive 3 logons, however, their system didnot logout by then and was heart beating until 23:04:34.142 UTC and
   then sent a test request to FIX Initiator at 23:04:41.141 UTC and as there was no response to the test request, FIX Acceptor initiated logout 23:05:35.142 UTC
   But FIX Initiator didn't receive HeartBeat or Test request from Acceptor side.

The FIX logs for reference:

**Event Logs:**

20230821-23:03:28: Initiated logon request

20230821-23:03:58: Initiated logon request

20230821-23:04:28: Initiated logon request

**Messages Logs:**

8=FIX.4.3  9=91  35=0  34=111  49=ldn  52=20230821-23:00:34.141  56=order.1  57=OSoft  10=174

8=FIX.4.3  9=91  35=0  34=112  49=order.1  50=OSoft  52=20230821-23:01:03.875  56=ldn  10=179

8=FIX.4.3  9=91  35=0  34=112  49=ldn  52=20230821-23:01:34.141  56=order.1  57=OSoft  10=176

8=FIX.4.3  9=91  35=0  34=113  49=order.1  50=OSoft  52=20230821-23:02:03.875  56=ldn  10=181

8=FIX.4.3  9=91  35=0  34=113  49=ldn  52=20230821-23:02:34.141  56=order.1  57=OSoft  10=178

8=FIX.4.3  9=91  35=0  34=114  49=order.1  50=OSoft  52=20230821-23:03:03.875  56=ldn  10=183

8=FIX.4.3  9=91  35=0  34=114  49=ldn  52=20230821-23:03:34.142  56=order.1  57=OSoft  10=181

8=FIX.4.3  9=135  35=A  34=1  49=order.1  50=OSoft  52=20230821-23:03:28.875  56=ldn  98=0  108=60  141=Y  553=FIXUser1  554=MkBj6sC  10=194

8=FIX.4.3  9=135  35=A  34=1  49=order.1  50=OSoft  52=20230821-23:03:58.875  56=ldn  98=0  108=60  141=Y  553=FIXUser1  554=MkBj6sC  10=197

8=FIX.4.3  9=135  35=A  34=1  49=order.1  50=OSoft  52=20230821-23:04:28.875  56=ldn  98=0  108=60  141=Y  553=FIXUser1  554=MkBj6sC  10=195

Question is - why the Quickfix stopped sending Logon request after 3 attempts?